# Post IdHTTP com Delphi

Tags: delphi, post, indy-10

Consigo fazer um post com HTML tranquilamente, mas quando tento fazer com Delphi, ele me apresenta este erro:

> http/1.1 406 not acceptable

Segue o código abaixo:

```
function TForm1.UploadArquivo(server, script, caminhoarq : string) : boolean;
var
  Response : String;
  HTTPClient : TIdHTTP;
  Lista : TStringList;
begin
  result := False;
  HTTPClient := TidHTTP.Create;
  HTTPClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_0;
  HTTPClient.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
  HTTPClient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
  Response := '';
  Lista := TStringList.Create;
  try
    try
      Lista.Add('Arquivo='+ caminhoarq);

      Response := Trim(HTTPClient.Post(server + script, Lista));
      Label1.Caption := Response;
      if Response = 'OK' then
        Result := true;
    finally
      Lista.Free;
      HTTPClient.free;
    end;
  except
    on e:exception do  ShowMessage('Erro ao enviar arquivo ao servidor! Detalhes: '+e.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Uso Delphi XE7, há alguma particularidade?

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse erro pode ser por causa dos símbolos, você deve trata-los antes de fazer a requisição!

```
HTTPClient := TidHTTP.Create;
HTTPClient.Request.ContentType := 'utf-8';
```

Também pode tentar assim:

```
Response := UTF8Decode(Trim(HTTPClient.Post(server + script, Lista)));
```

Mais uma coisa aqui:

```
HTTPClient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
```

Por mais incrivel que pareça, o "espaço" ali entre **compatible** e **Indy Library** pode causar o mesmo problema, então mude para:

```
HTTPClient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible;Indy Library)';
```

Comment: OBRIGADOOO!! Tudo certo amigo.