# Post IdHTTP FIREMONKEY Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Segue pergunta anterior:

[Pergunta Anterior sobre o mesmo assunto.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99094/post-idhttp-com-delphi/99102#99102)

Agora o que ele está mostrando é:

> http/1.1 404 Not Found.

Código utilizado:

Funcional em VCL:

```
function TForm1.UploadArquivo(server, script, caminhoarq : string) : boolean;
var
  Response, UploadURL : String;
  HTTPClient : TIdHTTP;
  Lista : TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  result := False;
  UploadURL := server + script;
  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  Lista := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  HTTPClient.ReadTimeout := 10000;
  HTTPClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  HTTPClient.Request.ContentType := 'utf-8';
  HTTPClient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible;Indy Library)';
  HTTPClient.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams,hoKeepOrigProtocol];
  Response := '';
  try
    try
      //Lista.Add('Arquivo='+ caminhoarq);
      Lista.AddFile('Arquivo', caminhoarq, 'application/octet-stream');
      Response := UTF8Decode(Trim(HTTPClient.Post(UploadURL, Lista)));
      //Label1.Text := Response;
      if Response = 'OK' then
        Result := true;
    except
      on e : exception do ShowMessage('Erro ao enviar arquivo ao servidor! Detalhes: '+e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Lista.Free;
    HTTPClient.free;
  end;
end;
```

Porém, o site existe, e verifiquei a string varias vezes, e mesmo assim, ele fica apresentando esta mensagem.

Agora estou testando em firemonkey, o mesmo código, pois acredito que não tenha mudado muita coisa, ou até mesmo nada.

Alguém tem ideia do que está ocorrendo?

------------------EDIT-----------------------

De acordo com os debugs que andei realizando, segue os comentários:

Nesta linha, o código para:

```
Response := UTF8Decode(Trim(HTTPClient.Post(UploadURL, Lista)));
```

Então fui mais a fundo. Na função `DoRequest`.

Ao tentar conectar com o Host, na função `CheckAndConnect`, que está situado dentro da função `ConnectToHost` ele retorna o erro 404 situado no `Response`.

Porém quando tento realizar o mesmo procedimento em um formulário em VCL. Ele funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Poste os códigos pra gente ver!

Comment: São esses que estão no link!

Comment: Boa tarde Ramon, recomendo que faça titulos intuitivos, o titulo das duas perguntas é praticamente igual e não remete ao problema da questão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, Boa tarde! Acho que foi esse o ponto, pois tudo é igual quando fiz para VCL, o que muda é que o erro anterior está Resolvido, e o de agora apresenta somente no FIREMONKEY.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento nenhuma ideéia do que possa ser?

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Alguma idéia cara?

Comment: @RamonRuan, faz seguinte, da um Breack nessa linha Response := UTF8Decode(Trim(HTTPClient.Post(UploadURL, Lista))); coloca o mouse sobre ela e vê se esta tudo ok! Se der anota e posta aqui!

Comment: Vou postar na pergunta os resultados.

Comment: @JúniorMoreira segue comentários sobre o debug, para ser mais direto, ele está retornando a exceção já de cara, ao tentar realizar o post.

Comment: Eu queria que você desse um breackpoint bem ali onde falei saka, coloca o mouse sobre, aperta F8 uma vez, ele vai seguir a linha, coloca o Mouse sobre a variável "Response" e veja o que ela recebeu!

Comment: Ela não recebe nada! justamente por causa do Erro!

Comment: @RamonRuan, retira o UTF8Decode que esta indo para o Response, deixe como você estava usando antes, se não der certo, teremos que partir para outra abordagem!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, mesma coisa!!

Comment: @RamonRuan, eu teria que ver o projeto inteiro, é inviável você postar o projeto aqui. Se quiser podemos fazer contato fora do SO, quando chegarmos a uma solução postamos aqui!

Comment: Obrigado Junior!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Senhores, acredito que foi algum conflito de nomes de string, pois no meu `private` eu estava utilizando o nome `ScriptUP`, após a mudança para o nome `ScriptUpload`, ele conseguiu pegar o Host, parece que não tem nada a ver, mas sinceramente, tem!

Solução foi mudar a string que estava captando o host/script para realizar o `post`.

Segue o código:

```
function TForm1.UploadArquivo(server, script, caminhoarq : string) : boolean;
var
  Response, URL : String;
  HTTPClient : TIdHTTP;
  Lista : TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  result := False;
  URL := server + script;
  Lista := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  HTTPClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  HTTPClient.Request.ContentType := 'utf-8';
  HTTPClient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible;Indy Library)';
  HTTPClient.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoKeepOrigProtocol];
  Response := '';
  try
    try
      Lista.AddFormField('Arquivo', caminhoarq);//, 'application/octet-stream');
      Response := UTF8Decode(Trim(HTTPClient.Post(URL, Lista)));
      if Response = 'OK' then
        Result := true;
    except
      on e : exception do ShowMessage('Erro ao enviar arquivo ao servidor! Detalhes: '+e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Lista.Free;
    HTTPClient.free;
  end;
end;
```